# NumberFormatException when attempting to Tokenize a String

Tags: java, file-io, runtime-error, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to tokenize a String and save it to a binary file, but when I run the program, I get a NumberFormatException. Here is my stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "  1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at Project6.saveBSAFile(Project6.java:187)
```

Here is my code, which is trying to tokenize a `String` and save it to a binary file:

```
public void saveBSAFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        jfc.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save");
        int userSelection = jfc.showSaveDialog(this);

        if (userSelection == jfc.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File filename = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File to save " + filename,
                                         "Save Review", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            FileOutputStream FOStream1 = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
            DataOutputStream DOStream1 = new DataOutputStream(FOStream1);
        }
        else if (userSelection == jfc.CANCEL_OPTION)
        {
            return;
        }

        int index = 0;

        while (tools.getNumberOfItems() <= 10 && processRec.getToolRecords(index) != null)
        {   
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(processRec.getToolRecords(index), "|:");

            toolStrTok = tokens.nextToken();
            toolNameTok = tokens.nextToken();
            idStrTok = tokens.nextToken();
            idTok = tokens.nextToken();
            qualStrTok = tokens.nextToken();
            qualTok = tokens.nextToken();
            stockStrTok = tokens.nextToken();
            stockTok = tokens.nextToken();
            priceStrTok = tokens.nextToken();
            priceTok = tokens.nextToken();

            idTok.trim();
            qualTok.trim();
            stockTok.trim();
            priceTok.trim();

            id = Integer.parseInt(idTok);
            quality = Integer.parseInt(qualTok);
            numInStock = Integer.parseInt(stockTok);
            price = Double.parseDouble(priceTok);

            FileOutputStream FOStream2 = new FileOutputStream(filename, true);
            DataOutputStream DOStream2 = new DataOutputStream(FOStream2);

            DOStream2.writeUTF(toolStrTok);
            DOStream2.writeUTF(" " + toolNameTok);
            DOStream2.writeUTF(" " + idStrTok + " ");
            DOStream2.writeInt(id);
            DOStream2.writeUTF(" " + qualStrTok + " ");
            DOStream2.writeInt(quality);
            DOStream2.writeUTF(" " + stockStrTok + " ");
            DOStream2.writeInt(numInStock);
            DOStream2.writeUTF(" " + priceStrTok + " ");
            DOStream2.writeDouble(price);
            DOStream2.close();

            index++;

        }//end loop 
    }//end saveBSAFile
```

And here is the String i'm attempting to tokenize, which is being pulled from a method in another class file(which is being referenced by a call to `processRec`):

```
public String getRecord(int index)
    {
        return "Tool Name:  " + toolArray[index].getName()
                + "| Tool ID:  " + toolArray[index].getToolID()
                + "| Tool Quality:  " + toolArray[index].getQuality()
                + "| Number in Stock:  " + toolArray[index].getNumberInStock()
                + "| Tool Price:  " + toolArray[index].getPrice();

    }//end getRecord
```

I've tried a few different things, such as trimming the `Strings` using `trim()` i'm attempting to tokenize, but that didnt seem to work :( I also tried reworking the code a bit but that hasn't netted me much luck, either. I'm very much a novice when it comes to exceptions and stack traces, so I was hoping someone may be able to point out any obvious(or not so obvious) mistakes I may be making. Thanks so much in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`trim()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) doesn't change the original `String`; it's immutable.

> **Returns** a string whose value is this string, with any leading and trailing whitespace removed.

(emphasis mine)

The `trim` method returns the trimmed `String`, but you discard the returned `String`.  `idTok` is still `"  1"`, with spaces.

Change

```
idTok.trim();
```

to

```
idTok = idTok.trim();
```

and likewise with the other tokens.  Then `parseInt` will see the trimmed string (e.g. `"1"`) and parse the integers correctly.

Comment: Wow, and that was the one thing I was confident I got correct lol. Perhaps I need a history refresher. I really appreciate you pointing that out.